# jQuery multiselect not able to remove options with a click event

Tags: jquery, html, select, multi-select

I am using the multiselect ([multiselect website](http://quasipartikel.at/multiselect/)) jQuery plugin. It works perfectly, but for my purposes I need to add a reset button to my page, that when you click on it, it will remove all the options selected already and reset the multiselect back to default state.

I have managed to remove the options by removing the selected attribute from the select box it attaches itself too, but it does not update the html in the multiselect so in actual fact the select box has nothing selected, just the html remains the same.

Unfortunately the plugin is not well documented and I am forced to use this one (as per clients request) so does anyone else know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This multiselect widget uses the jQuery UI widget framework, but does not seem to provide a `refresh()` method to update the widget when the state of the augmented element changes.

You can, however, emulate it by going through a full destroy / create cycle:

```
$("#yourElement").multiselect("destroy").multiselect({
    // Your options...
});
```

Comment: Hey @Frederic, thank you for your reply! I have copied your suggestion but my js breaks with an error "$.widget.prototype.destroy is undefined". Is it possible that the multiselect does not have a destroy option?

Comment: @Mauritz, the widget definitely exposes a `destroy()` method (line 134 in the source code [here](https://github.com/michael/multiselect/blob/master/js/ui.multiselect.js)). The error might result from a compatibility issue with jQuery UI, which version are you including? Also, can you confirm `$.widget` in the error message does not have a capital `W`? (it should.)

Comment: I can confirm that it definately has a lowercase "w", I am using jquery UI version 1.8.21.min

Comment: @Mauritz, then I would suggest you update the multiselect plugin. The current version in GitHub uses `$.Widget` instead, which is mandatory with recent releases of jQuery UI.

Comment: excellent suggestion. It did not entirely fix my solution but it did fix another unrelated styling issue I had. I manage to, with your suggestion above, run another line to remove the selected attributes from the actual select box first and then destroy the instance, else it keeps the selected options. Thank you for your advice :)

Comment: Thanks for this answer and thanks for the question..saved my lots of time :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's simple, you need to remove the attribute to the original select
and just refresh the content.

```
$("#my-select option[value=\""+this.valeur+"\"]").remove();
$('#my-select').multiselect('refresh');
```